# Xamarin.Forms app shows blue screen on IOS then the app closes

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So when testing my app on an android emulator i had no problems, but when i tested my app on iOS, i get the starting blue screen of Xamarin then the app closes and i am taken to all the apps page on the emulator ( but it acts like it's still running since you still see the red square on visual studio that shows when the app is running).

So i don't get any error message, so i am not sure how i can find the problem since i'm new in mobile dev.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot !

[image]

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Calculette.App">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using Calculette.Database;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

//[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace Calculette
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        
        static CalculetteDatabase database;
        public static CalculetteDatabase Database
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    
                    database = new CalculetteDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Calculette.db3"));
        
                }
                return database;
            }
        }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //MainPage = new MainPage();
            // Pour pouvoir faire apparaitre la toolbaritems
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            ((NavigationPage)MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#008A00");
            ((NavigationPage)MainPage).BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF");
            

        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate.cs for iOS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace Calculette.iOS

    {
        // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
        // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
        // application events from iOS.
        [Register("AppDelegate")]
        public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
        {
            //
            // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
            // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
            // visible.
            //
            // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
            //
            public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
            {
    
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags(new string[] { "Expander_Experimental", "SwipeView_Experimental" });
                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
                LoadApplication(new App());
    
                return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Main.cs for iOS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

    namespace Calculette.iOS
    {
        public class Application
        {
            // This is the main entry point of the application.
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
                // you can specify it here.
                UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Debug output when the app is loading then the blue screen closes and you see the initial screen with all the apps**

```
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(System.String[], System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)' to /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.20.2.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:85 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/Calculette.iOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Data.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Transactions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Drawing.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.IO.Compression.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Web.Services.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/Calculette.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/XamForms.Controls.Calendar.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Threading.Tasks.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Globalization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user179537/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBBD6116-A257-42AB-B54A-9C00DF68934D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/31B4CC71-FFB9-4A92-946F-B35391E22175/Calculette.iOS.app/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calculette"
            xmlns:pv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
            xmlns:views1="clr-namespace:Calculette.Views"
            xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Calculette.Converters"
            x:Class="Calculette.MainPage"
            BarBackgroundColor = "White"
            BarTextColor="#008A00">


    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="logocalculette.png"></ToolbarItem>

        <ToolbarItem></ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem></ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Calculette de bruit"/>

        <ToolbarItem Text=""></ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="À propos" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Références" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Mentions légales" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Aide" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Options" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>


    <views1:TasksGroupPage></views1:TasksGroupPage>
    <local:CalendarPage></local:CalendarPage>




</TabbedPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Calculette.ViewModels;
using Calculette.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;
using Calculette.Views;

namespace Calculette
{
    public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.TabbedPage.SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(this, false);
            

        }


     }
}
```

Comment: what does the application output window show?

Comment: @Jason which window do you need, for output i have choice between build, build order, Debug, Package Manager, Xamarin, Xamarin Diagnostic. Also an other behavior, is that once the app is installed on the emulator, when i run the project again, it will never start the app instantly, i need to click on the app icon for it to launch

Comment: I adde dthe debug output, it seems like it's stuck there (at least 10 mins and nothing happened)

Comment: @codetime Hi, when the app closes , could you share the logs of the OutPut of VS? In addittion, if can share some code of `Fomrs` , that will be better.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hello, sorry i am not sure what code of Fomrs is, where is that located ? And which output of Vs do you want, i got the options from my second comment and theres the debut output in the post already . Thanks !

Comment: You dont need to share the MainActivity.cs since that is a file only needed for Android. Is there a way to share your code through GitHub so I can help you figure it out? Also can you share the code in your App.xaml.cs and App.xaml files. Also, share the code in the MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs if you have those. PS: Jiang meant `Forms` code which is the shared/core project that contains the files that I am asking you to share the code of

Comment: @codetime Hi, Saamer's comment is what I mean. And the `OutPut` logs can collect as follow steps in VS: Click **View->OutPut**, then you will see logs there like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC9U5.png).

Comment: @Saamer i added what you told me to add MainPage and App

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT the debug output that i included in the post is exactly what i see, the app doesn't get any error, it just loads the assembly, and then the app closes and i land on the icons of the phone page. I don't know if it matter but i am using macincloud to test the app on iOS

Comment: @Saamer here's the repo https://github.com/danypepin1/Calculette

Comment: @codetime Thanks for sharing the repo, I will check that.

Comment: @codetime From shared repo, I found that there are something wrong with `CalendarPage`. If comment this line `<!--<local:CalendarPage></local:CalendarPage>-->` in `MainPage.xaml`, you will see the view in iOS. About the detail reason, you need to check this `CalendarPage`. The Xaml of `CalendarPage` seems to be complex. And even run in Android, when clicking the day of date, the output will show warnning:`Binding: '' can not be converted to type 'Xamarin.Forms.Color'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the repo in local site, find that the problem is **CalendarPage**.And after check that, the problem comes from **ViewModel**.

The `BindingContext` of **CalendarPage** is:

```
public CalendarPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = new CalendarPageViewModel();
}
```

If comment `BindingContext`, iOS will show view. **However**, when click *CalendarPage* tab, the view will always hold on that moment.

[image]

Therefore, the problem should be the **CalendarPageViewModel**. After checking that, when `new CalendarPageViewModel()`, it will invoke a Task thread. However, `ListViewCollection.ItemsSource` re-call the Task thread. It will deadlock your UI thread.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{

    base.OnAppearing();
    var vm = this.BindingContext as CalendarPageViewModel;
    Calendar.SelectedDates.Clear();
    vm.Date = null;
    vm.ExpanderBool = false;
    vm.PancakeViewBool = false;
       
    await vm.GetTasks();
    await vm.Initialize();
    ListViewCollection.ItemsSource = vm.Tasks;
}
```

Last, I find a **workaround** can make the app works in iOS. I'm not sure whehter it will affect some functions in this project, because I'm not the designer of this app and not familiar with it.

Comment the `Initialize` method in the constructor method of **CalendarPageViewModel** as follow:

```
public CalendarPageViewModel()
{
    //Initialize().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    DeleteClickedCommand = new Command(new Action<object>(async (obj) =>
    {

        await DeleteClicked(obj);
    }));

    ResultPageClickedCommand = new Command(new Action<object>(async (obj) =>
    {

        await ResultPageClicked(obj);
    }));

    AddTaskButtonClickedCommand = new Command(new Action<object>(async (obj) =>
    {

        await AddTaskButtonClicked(obj);
    }));
}
```

It will show no problem in iOS:

[image]

=================================update=================================

If you not adding the title and icon source for tabbar item, iOS will not show them.

**MainPage.xml** modified as follow:

```
...
<views1:TasksGroupPage Title="TasksGroup" IconImageSource="iconcalendrier.png"></views1:TasksGroupPage>
<local:CalendarPage Title="Calendar" IconImageSource="icontache.png"></local:CalendarPage>
...
```

Not forgetting to add icon source in iOS **Resources** folder.

[image]

The effect:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out, really appreciated. I think he didn't like .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); so i reimplemented so it doesn't use it and it seems to work all good, thanks again !

Comment: Sucks that the toolbar items at the top doesn't behave the same as android with an hamburger menu haha

Comment: @codetime The reason is that iOS solution not adding icon source in `Resources` folder. I will update the answer. In addition, the tab title also will now show if not add that.

Comment: True i forgot to add those icons, but i was talking about the  A propos, references, etc. at the top on Android it's an hamburger menu called toolbaritems and on iOS it's all expanded and ugly haha but i've read that iOS don't like hamburger menu ?

Comment: @codetime Yes, iOS doesn't have the same toolbar with Android.If need that, it should custom the page in iOS.